# angular2+ how to use <select> with [value] and set [selected]

Tags: angular

so I have this code:

```
<select #sceneSelection (change)="_onSceneSelectionChanged($event.target.value)"formControlName="sceneSelection">
           <option [selected]="scene.selected" [value]="scene.sceneId" *ngFor="let scene of m_sceneSelection">{{scene.label}}</option>
 </select>
```

and one of my scenes has a selected.true, seems simple enough but I can't get the drop down to select the item I need.

Now, if I remove my [value]="" my selection works, but I won't get the ID in event.target.value, and I need the ID passed back to me, not the string the shows in the UI.

regards

Sean

Comment: Works for me: http://plnkr.co/edit/J6YezDkquwe4xNMPG0rc?p=preview&open=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

this solved it

```
<select #sceneSelection [(ngModel)]="m_sceneSeleced.id" style="height: 30px" (change)="_onSceneSelectionChanged($event.target.value)"formControlName="sceneSelection">
      <option [selected]="scene.selected" [value]="scene.sceneId" *ngFor="let scene of m_sceneSelection">{{scene.label}}</option>
 </select>
```

had to add both [selected] as well as ngModel, otherwise selection did not work.